# Не подключается библиотека validate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подключение библиотек.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='/../../web/index.js' type="module"></script>
```

файл index.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.send', function() {
    
    var validateForm = $(document).find('#contacsform');
    validateForm.validate({
        rules: {
            fromPerson: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            fromPlace: {
                required: true,                
                minlength: 5
            },
            toPerson:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            toPlace:{
                required: true,                
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            fromPerson: {
                required: "Введите Ваше Имя",
                minlength: "Имя должно быть более 2-х символов"
                
            }            
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {                
            form.submit();
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {                 
            var item = element.parents('.item');
            item.append(error);
        }
    });
 
    validateForm.submit();
});
```

при нажатии на кнопку выдает ошибку

```
index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: validateForm.validate is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.js:5)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:5429)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5233)
```

Comment: прочтите документацию https://validatejs.org/, тут написано что и как

Comment: @AndreyFreiz я уже ознакомился с документацией, пробовал подлкючать черезе npm но ошибка так и остается